# case-insensitive alphabetical sorting of nested lists

Tags: python

i'm trying to sort this nested list by inner's list first element:

```
ak = [ ['a',1],['E',2],['C',13],['A',11],['b',9] ]
ak.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[0], y[0]))
for i in ak: {
    print i
}
```

by default python considers A > a, hence the output i get is:

```
['A', 11] ['C', 13] ['E', 2] ['a', 1] ['b', 9]
```

i've tried converting all list values to even case during comparison by adding x[0].lower etc. but no use. How do i force python (i'm working on 2.4 version) to do case-insensitive alphabetical sorting?

**Edited:**

> Jarret and Brian, your
>   assumptions about parenthesis were
>   right! I did forget to put them in! And Jarret, your suggestions about not using "cmp" works like a charm! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
ak.sort(key=lambda x:x[0].lower())
```

I would recommend that you avoid using `cmp` as this has been deprecated in Python 2.6, and removed in 3.0. I know you're using 2.4, but the reason `cmp` has fallen into disfavour is that it is a very slow way to sort.

I'm not sure why your effort with `lower` failed, though... perhaps you forgot to use the function call versus just the function name? (ie: `cmp(x[0].lower(), y[0].lower())` versus `cmp(x[0].lower, y[0].lower)`)

Answer (score 3):

```
ak.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[0].lower(), y[0].lower()))
```

Did you forget the parens in `x[0].lower()`?